# Julia: rational behind array size and index for "extra" dimensions?

Tags: arrays, julia

I am using Julia from time to time, however I am surprised by the following behavior:

Let's define an 3x4 array

```
julia> m=rand(3,4)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.889018  0.500847  0.539856  0.828231 
 0.492425  0.582958  0.521406  0.754102 
 0.28227   0.834333  0.669967  0.0939701
```

Now I check that

```
julia> size(m,1), size(m,2)
(3, 4)
```

as expected.

**However, I am surprised by this:**

```
julia> size(m,3), size(m,2018)
(1, 1)
```

-> I would have expected `(0,0)` or an `error message`

Looking the Julia code confirms this behavior:

```
size(t::AbstractArray{T,N}, d) where {T,N} = d <= N ? size(t)[d] : 1
```

**Moreover**:

```
julia> m[2,1,1,1,1]
0.4924252391289974
```

-> I would have expected an `out of bounds error`

**So my question is: "what is the rationale?"**
( I do not thing it is a bug, I use Julia version 0.6.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's for broadcasting.

```
julia> m=rand(3,4)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.139323  0.663912  0.994985   0.517332
 0.423913  0.121753  0.0327054  0.0754665
 0.392672  0.47006   0.351121   0.787318

julia> size(m)
(3, 4)

julia> n = rand(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.716752
 0.98755
 0.661226

julia> m .* n
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.09986   0.475861  0.713157   0.370799
 0.418636  0.120237  0.0322983  0.074527
 0.259645  0.310816  0.23217    0.520595
```

Notice that `n` is of one dimension less, so it's size 1 in the 2nd dimension and thus applies column-wise. Scalars in broadcast are treated differently and are generally inlined into the fused broadcasting function which you cannot do with a mutable type, so the size 1 = expand in higher dimensions rule for broadcast is a nice way to implement this.

Comment: I do agree with your answer, it is my opinion too. Wanted to check, though

Comment: But it's not just practical, it also makes sense. An array of size 2x0 has to be empty. If any dimension has length zero, then the product of the dimension lengths is zero, which means there is no space for any elements.

Comment: Yes, size is always the product of the length in each dimension, so that's another way to intuitively see it should have length 1 in higher dimensions.